# Remote Spring boot app still connect to my local mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, angular, spring-boot

I work with Angular 4, Spring boot and Mysql. In local, all works fine. I try to deployed on a remote server, a Centos 7. All works fine except that when I access to my website, it takes data from my local database, and not from the mysql database which is located on the remote server.

I tried on another computer and the result is the same, it takes data from local computer !

Here is my Spring boot's application.properties file:

```
server.port = 8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

`netstat -tln` on the remote server (Only usefull fields):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q local address           remote address          State       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Mysql databases have exactly the same structure, and the same username/password.

**-- UPDATE --**

Thanks for suggestions, I finnally solved this problem. It came from the connection between Angular and Spring, and not from Spring and Mysql.

A Springboot instance was running on my local computer, and the remote Angular was connected to it. In Angular's config file, I replaced `apiUrl=localhost:8081` by `apiUrl=<my remote IP>:8081`, deploy again, I opened the port 8081 (port of Springboot) to everyone and now it works well.

But to be honest, I don't like this method because my Springboot app is accessible by everyone, whereas it need to be accessible only by the Angular app. If someone have a solution, this question is still open. Thanks

Comment: You are tellung your jdbc driver to connect to `localhost` via the datasource url. So connecting to localhost is exactly what it will do. Why should it do something else?

Comment: The app is deploy on a remote server, so the localhost is the remote server, not my own device

Comment: Have you checked your code if your local machine isn't referenced (by ip or hostname) anyhwere? Could be everything at this point.

Comment: No, and if it were the case, when I tried on a new computer, it should have take data from my previous device, but it take data from the new computer.. (A mysql database with the same structure was set up on the new compteur too)

Comment: Are you using Spring's `profile` support? Is it possible that you are starting the application with a different `spring.profiles.active` in the remote environment such that it is reading from a different `properties` file? It does, though, seem highly suspect that a remote server would be reading from the database installed on your development machine, especially if you were using `localhost` that seems all but impossible... how are you certain that it is reading from your local database?

Comment: I do not even understand your setup, to be honest. How can an angular app access the client's computer to get a db connection? Something there doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Florian Haha i'm totally agree, and here is the problem ! I dont understand me neither ...

Comment: @Ben thanks for suggestion, i'll try tomorrow morning, and yes i'm sure, I made a lot of test, even on 2 computer.

Comment: I suggest you create an SSCCE (a short, self-contained, correct example). A minimal program where this problem occurs and post the details, perhaps then people can help. In most cases, this example will not show the error, so by adding details you can find out where the error is for yourself.

Comment: @Ben try to separate the problem in small parts.  If you are using angular then you should test the services that your angular app is consuming. From your local computer try to access your services directly without angular and verify the data that you get directly from services.  Also go to your server and connect to mysql database and compare the data.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestion, I solved the problem but I am not satisfied by it. Please take a look to the question's update.

Answer (score 1):

Without being sure i think you need to point your datasource url to the remote location. Example:

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.166:3306/yourSchema?characterEncoding\=UTF-8
database.username=username
database.password=password
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the problem is still here.. And I think it's possible to access to a local mysql with localhost instead of IP, it avoid to open the mysql port to everyone

Answer (score 1):

due to incorrect password - instead mysql complains password it shows error connecting with local IP , check your password twice